# Delphi - Finding Memory leak

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

Delphi Rio - I have a simple routine that takes a string and deletes all text within parentheses.  When I call this routine (20,000 times), I get an Out of Memory Error.  If I skip this routine, my code properly completes.  I do not understand why this is causing an out of memory error, let alone how to fix it.  The code functionally works, but it is causing a memory issue.  Can someone identify what is causing this/how to fix?

```
function glib_RemoveParenText(S: string): string;
var
 TagBegin, TagEnd, TagLength: Integer;

begin
  TagBegin := Pos('(', S); // search position of first (
  while (TagBegin > 0) do
   begin // while there is a ( in S
    TagEnd := Pos(')', S); // find the matching )

    // Check to see if we have a starting Paren without ending Paren...
    if TagEnd = 0 then
      TagEnd := Length(S);

    TagLength := TagEnd - TagBegin + 1;

    // Then delete it from the string
    delete(S, TagBegin, TagLength); // delete the tag
    TagBegin := Pos('(', S); // search for next (
  end;

  Result := S; // give the result

 end;
```

Comment: What are you doing with the result of this function? How long (approximately) is the original string.

Comment: The original string will vary, but is normally between 50-150 bytes. Once I call this function, I do other string processing, such as break it into words, and make each word singular, get rid of words I am not interested in (A, AN, THE, OF, etc)

Comment: You are assuming that ) follows (.  Your code will misbehave when this is not the case like for `Test ) text in brackets (`. Search for the closing bracket starting after the opening bracket.

Comment: Their eos no leak in the code shown. But, maybe there is a leak elsewhere. Have you enabled `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown`? Is it reporting any leaks? If not, then there is no real leak, but maybe you are fragmenting memory instead, causing freed memory to be un-reusable so it takes up space.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. Probably caused by code elsewhere in your application. Did you tried to call the function from within a simple program? A tool like madExcept will show you where the leaked memory has been allocated. I like madExcept very much but there are other tools, including FastMM and Deleaker.

Comment: Change `TagEnd := Pos(')', S);` to   `TagEnd := Pos(')', S,TagBegin);` to avoid problems with extra closing brackets that end up before opening brackets. Testing it doesn't seem to consume memory (Just a lot of CPU) so likely not related to OOM problems.

Comment: @fpiette And EurekaLog

Comment: I had used ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown earlier.  It was showing a leak.  It appears my problem was actually 2 issues.  I had fixed the leak in the code posted, but the app was locking up on nested parenthesis.  The code change suggested by Brian fixed it.  Post as answer, and I will accept.